# Apollo Federation (Gateway): how to send different "keys" to different implementing microservices?

Tags: apollo, apollo-federation, ariadne-graphql, apollo-gateway

I am trying to compose a federated apollo service with a gateway and 3 implementing microservices.

**MS1:**

```
type Movie @key(fields: "id name") {
    id: String!
    name: String
}
```

**MS2:**

```
type Location @key(fields: "id") {
    id: String!
    longitude: Float!
    latitude: Float!
} 

type Movie @key(fields: "id") @extends {
    id: String! @external
    location: Location
}
```

**MS3:**

```
type Award @key(fields: "name"){
    name: String!
    count: Int
} 

type Movie @key(fields: "name") @extends {
    name: String! @external
    award: Award
}
```

MS1 provides a *name* and an *id*.
*name* shall be send to MS3 for the resolving process and *id* shall be used by MS2 for the resolving process.

This approach worked with an older version of apollo-gateway / apollo-server, but with the latest versions I receive the following error messages.

```
{"stack":"Error: A valid schema couldn't be composed. The following composition errors were found:\n\t[ms2] Movie -> extends from ms1 but specifies an invalid @key directive. Valid @key directives are specified by the originating type. Available @key directives for this type are:\n\t@key(fields: \"id name\")\n   ...}
```

An approach to provide the keys like this didn't work either:

```
type Movie @key(fields: "id") @key(fields: "name") {
```

What does the schema have to look like to provide the described use case?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Not one I am very happy with, but I got it working like this:
Keep MS 1 as it is. Then change on MS 2:

type Location \@key(fields: "id") {
    id: String!
    longitude: Float!
    latitude: Float!
} 

type Movie \@key(fields: "id name") @extends {
    id: String! \@external
    name: String! \@external
    location: Location
}

MS2 now gets name also, even if it doesn't need it for anything.
MS3 can be changed accordingly.

Also, remove backslashes in front of the \@ . Had to escape them for stackoverflow :(